# incorrect auto-indent in bash code

Tags: indentation

I have bash script which Vim detects as a `sh` according to `:set filetype?`. In addition, Vim-script for auto-indention support for shell-scripts(`/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/sh.vim`) is also present. However, for example following while loop:

```
while read -ra line"$line_id"_fields; do
  line_id=$((line_id+1))
done < "$1"
```

..is auto intended(`gg=G`) to this:

```
  while read -ra line"$line_id"_fields; do
line_id=$((line_id+1))
  done < "$1"
```

What might cause this?

Comment: Works for me on Vim 7.4.2143; which version are you using?

Comment: Make sure, you have `:filetype plugin indent on` in your .vimrc. Then in your shell script check that `:verbose set indentexpr?` returns something like this:  `indentexpr=GetShIndent()
        Zuletzt gesetzt von /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/sh.vim`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I'm using Vim version 7.4.576. @Christian Brabandt Thanks! `filetype indent on` was missing. Once I added this to my `.vimrc` file, auto-indention feature works fine. I actually tried that before, but for some reason `filetype indent on` works only if I set this in my `.vimrc` file. If I have the bash script open and type `filetype indent on`(and I can confirm that it is on with `filetype` command), then auto-indent does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Christian Brabandt mentioned in his comment, `filetype indent on` was missing from my `.vimrc` file.